# Singleclick on OpenLayers for multiple layers

Tags: openlayers, layers, features, url

I want to get information on click only for selected layer, but it seems like I get it for random one every time I click on.

Here is my code:

```
map.on("singleclick", function (evt) {
  var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel);
  if (features.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";
    var f = features[0].getProperties();
    delete f["geometry"];
    document.getElementById("fInfo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(f);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("fInfo").innerHTML = "";

    const viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (map.getView().getResolution());
    const url1 = wmsSource1.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate,
      viewResolution,
      "EPSG:3857",
      { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
    );
    const url2 = wmsSource2.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, 
      viewResolution, 
      "EPSG:3857", 
      { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
      );
    const url3 = wmsSource3.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, 
      viewResolution, 
      "EPSG:3857", 
      { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
      );
    const url4 = wmsSource4.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, 
      viewResolution, 
      "EPSG:3857", 
      { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
      );
    const url5 = wmsSource5.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, 
      viewResolution, 
      "EPSG:3857", 
      { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
      );
    const url6 = wmsSource6.getFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, 
      viewResolution, 
      "EPSG:3857", 
      { INFO_FORMAT: "text/html" }
      );

    if (url1) {
      fetch(url1)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });
    } else if (url2) {
      fetch(url2)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });
    } else if (url3) {
      fetch(url3)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });
    } else if (url4) {
      fetch(url4)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });
    } else if (url5) {
      fetch(url5)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });
    } else {
      fetch(url6)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = html;
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is your problem with `getFeaturesAtPixel` or the WMS sources?  `getFeaturesAtPixel` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getFeaturesAtPixel returns features from all vector layers unless you specify a layer filter in the options.  And your `wmsSource1` will always return a url, so none of the other sources will be fetched.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "selected layer"?

Comment: By selected layer I mean that I use layerSwitcher, so when I switch to a specific layer I consider it selected.